# align center with all padding

Tags: html, css

I need to align the elements so that everyone in the block stands exactly without extra spaces

I do it with justify-content: center, elements are centered but look like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mb5kV.png)

But I need everything to be even, but at the same time it also remains in the center, without extra spaces, like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Izcb.png)

important note, when the screen width is larger, the elements should not be in a column but in a row, this is now done, I deliberately reduced the width so that they do not fit

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 200px;
}
.item {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 28px;
  display: flex;
}
.item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 16px;
}
.item svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 0;
}
.item span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  max-width: 200px;
}
.item img {
  width: 30px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
   <div class="item">
     <span>Australia <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Ad3jzMI.jpg"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
     <span>Italy <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Ad3jzMI.jpg"></span>
   </div>
    <div class="item">
     <span>Germany <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Ad3jzMI.jpg"></span>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a wrapper (i.e., `<div class="wrapper">`), everything else can stay the same. The trick is that now **the wrapper is centered**.

See the snippet below.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 28px;
  display: flex;
}

.item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 16px;
}

.item svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 0;
}

.item span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  max-width: 200px;
}

.item img {
  width: 30px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item">
      <span>Australia <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Ad3jzMI.jpg"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span>Italy <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Ad3jzMI.jpg"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span>Germany <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Ad3jzMI.jpg"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**EDIT 1**

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.item {
  padding-left: 28px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 16px;
}

.item svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 0;
}

.item span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  max-width: 200px;
}

.item img {
  width: 30px;
  margin-left: 7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item">
      <span>Australia <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Ad3jzMI.jpg"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span>Italy <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Ad3jzMI.jpg"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span>Germany <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Ad3jzMI.jpg"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**EDIT 2**

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.item {
  padding-left: 28px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 16px;
}

.item svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 0;
}

.item span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  max-width: 200px;
}

.item img {
  width: 30px;
  margin-left: 7px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
  .item {
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item">
      <span>Australia <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Ad3jzMI.jpg"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span>Italy <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Ad3jzMI.jpg"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span>Germany <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Ad3jzMI.jpg"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the fact is that when the screen width is larger, they should all go in a row, and it turns out that they will always be in a column

Comment: yes, this is something similar, but now when the width decreases, there is no centering, all elements go from the beginning

Answer (score 0):

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.item {
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.item svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 0;
}
.item span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  max-width: 200px;
}
.item img {
  width: 30px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
   <div class="item">
     <span>Australia</span> <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Ad3jzMI.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
     <span>Italy</span> <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Ad3jzMI.jpg">
   </div>
    <div class="item">
     <span>Germany</span> <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Ad3jzMI.jpg">
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: when the screen width is larger, they should all go in a row, and it turns out that they will always be in a column

Comment: use flex wrap on the parent and give some width for the childs as you started, that should work

Comment: @someone I've edited the answer for you

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are adding `img` after the text of `span`, not after `span` itself.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 200px;
}
.item {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}
.item svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 0;
}
.item span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 200px;
}
.item img {
  width: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
   <div class="item">
     <span>Australia</span><img src="https://i.imgur.com/Ad3jzMI.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
     <span>Italy</span><img src="https://i.imgur.com/Ad3jzMI.jpg">
   </div>
    <div class="item">
     <span>Germany</span><img src="https://i.imgur.com/Ad3jzMI.jpg">
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: unfortunately I can’t do it any other way, and the image must be in span

Comment: Then you have to separate span text into another html tag. The problem is that if you put image next to text, image is like and extension of text. Its start point will be the endpoint of text. Obvioulsy you dont want this, because `Italy` takes less space than `Australia`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this? Hope this answer helps.

You can find more information on flexbox layout here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.flex {
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 200px;
}
.item {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 28px;
}
.item .wrapper{
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  max-width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: left;
}
.item img {
  width: 30px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
   <div class="item">
     <span class="wrapper"><span class='country'>Australia</span> <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Ad3jzMI.jpg"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
     <span class="wrapper"><span class='country'>Italy</span> <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Ad3jzMI.jpg"></span>
   </div>
    <div class="item">
     <span class="wrapper"><span class='country'>Germany</span> <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Ad3jzMI.jpg"></span>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="flex">
    <div>
        <div class="item">
            <span>Australia <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Ad3jzMI.jpg"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <span>Italy <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Ad3jzMI.jpg"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <span>Germany <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Ad3jzMI.jpg"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Add one more child and wrap all child elements. Its will center the inner content, still keep the child elements in same position.